# Using multithreading with JDBC connection java in multiple levels

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, concurrency

I'm trying to use a multithreaded program that acts as below :
{X1, X2, ..., Xn} are objects that will be in a list.

each of the **X** objects, will need to call an **Y** function, and **Y** function will need to call **Z** function.

Example :

```
void getX() { 
      ....
 X.setY(getY());
}

Y getY() {
  ...
 Y.setZ(getZ())
}
```

**What i want is to split my getX functions into several threads to be run in parallel, cause i'm calling it multiple times (from a for loop).**

**NB**: getX, getY and getZ are using JDBC connection to retrieve data from database.

I did something like :

```
getX() {
 List<X> list = new ArrayList<>();
 Runnable task = () -> {
  X x = new X();
  x.setY(getY())
  list.add(x)
 }
 Thread thread = new Thread(task);
 thread.start();
}
```

I know i'm doing it wrong as the values of Y and Z may not be filled as its concurrent.
I'm little confused for how to do it . Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You may be looking for `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`

Comment: in my case , CompletableFuture is not running in parallel.

Comment: I meant that time processing with or without it its the same.